# Python Error on Examine Different Modelling

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I am new to Python and I am trying to examine different models to see which model has higher accuracy.
However, when I test it, I encountered an issue with some of the models

The error is: TypeError: Cannot clone object '<class 'sklearn.tree._classes.DecisionTreeClassifier'>' (type <class 'abc.ABCMeta'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.

I have attached the code below:

```
seed = 6
scoring = 'accuracy'

models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC()))

results = []
names = []

for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits =10, random_state = seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, x_train, y_train, cv = kfold, scoring = scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

The sklearn version is: 0.22.1

The results with errors shows below:

```
LR: 0.950000 (0.076376)
LDA: 0.975000 (0.038188)
KNN: 0.958333 (0.055902)
D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py:296: FutureWarning: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. This will raise an error in 0.24. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True.
  FutureWarning
D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py:940: ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
  extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG)
D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py:940: ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
  extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG)
D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py:940: ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
  extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG)
D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py:296: FutureWarning: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. This will raise an error in 0.24. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True.
  FutureWarning
D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py:296: FutureWarning: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. This will raise an error in 0.24. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True.
  FutureWarning
D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py:296: FutureWarning: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. This will raise an error in 0.24. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True.
  FutureWarning
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    796             try:
--> 797                 tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
    798             except queue.Empty:

D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\queue.py in get(self, block, timeout)
    166                 if not self._qsize():
--> 167                     raise Empty
    168             elif timeout is None:

Empty: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-b6b9556f713c> in <module>
     14 for name, model in models:
     15     kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits =10, random_state = seed)
---> 16     cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, x_train, y_train, cv = kfold, scoring = scoring)
     17     results.append(cv_results)
     18     names.append(name)

D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, error_score)
    388                                 fit_params=fit_params,
    389                                 pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch,
--> 390                                 error_score=error_score)
    391     return cv_results['test_score']
    392 

D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    234             return_times=True, return_estimator=return_estimator,
    235             error_score=error_score)
--> 236         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
    237 
    238     zipped_scores = list(zip(*scores))

D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1002             # remaining jobs.
   1003             self._iterating = False
-> 1004             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1005                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1006 

D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    806                 big_batch_size = batch_size * n_jobs
    807 
--> 808                 islice = list(itertools.islice(iterator, big_batch_size))
    809                 if len(islice) == 0:
    810                     return False

D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    234             return_times=True, return_estimator=return_estimator,
    235             error_score=error_score)
--> 236         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
    237 
    238     zipped_scores = list(zip(*scores))

D:\Anaconda\installation\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     65                             "it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator "
     66                             "as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods."
---> 67                             % (repr(estimator), type(estimator)))
     68     klass = estimator.__class__
     69     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)

TypeError: Cannot clone object '<class 'sklearn.tree._classes.DecisionTreeClassifier'>' (type <class 'abc.ABCMeta'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.
```

Thank you so much, everyone, really appreciate it.

Comment: You're missing parentheses/arguments for the decision tree.

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved it now.